# Exclude Featured Post from Custom Query WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the custom query I'm running to display post from 2 categories.
I have installed WordPress Plugin "Featured Post" but the featured post is not excluding from the displayed list.

```
<?php 
     $category_id = get_cat_ID($strReports || $strInsights);
     $custom_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=' .$category_id. '&featured=no&posts_per_page=6&order=desc' );
     while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
?> 

HTML Content Here

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); // reset the query ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure featured=no is the correct query parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Looking through "Featured Post" you can see that it just test against *yes* value. What `feature=yes` does is just check a meta field, so I think you can do the reverse way to achieve what you want, like this:

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => $category_id,
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'order' => 'DESC', // since order default value is already DESC you can remove this line
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => '_is_featured',
            'value' => 'yes',
            'compare' => '!=',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_is_featured',
            'value' => 'foo', // Prior to WP 3.9 we have to provide any non-empty string here
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ) ,
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

your'e running an invalid argument on [get_cat_ID](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID).

should be something like this:

```
<?php 
     $cat_names  = array('Cat_Name1', 'Cat_Name2');
     $category_Name = implode(',', $cat_names);
     $args = array(
        'category_name' =>  $category_Name,
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'featured', 
                    'value' => true, 
                    'compare' => '!=',
                ),
            ), 
     );
     $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
     while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
?> 

<?php the_title();?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); // reset the query ?>
```

Comment: i have added the same code you have given but no post showing now.

Answer (score 0):

create your custom query and add filter.

```
function SearchFilter($query){

$query=" SELECT Distinct SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.* FROM `$wpdb->posts` as p left join `$wpdb->postmeta` as m on m.post_id=p.ID "
                ." left join `$wpdb->term_relationships` as r ON (p.ID = r.object_id) "
                ." left join `$wpdb->term_taxonomy` as x ON (x.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id) "
                ." left join `$wpdb->terms` as t ON (t.term_id = x.term_id AND x.taxonomy='category') "
                ." WHERE p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish' "
                ." AND t.term_id='$idcategorie' "

return $query;
}
add_filter( 'posts_request', 'SearchFilter' );
```